# How do I add more than one Dropdownlist in an ActionResult in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to add another dropdownlist. The below code works for one dropdown, but how would I add one for Categories?

```
public  ActionResult Create()
        {
            var ddl = new Users();
            ddl.DropDowns = userRepository.Getddl("Departments").Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                                                    {
                                                                        Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
                                                                        Text = c.DropdownText
                                                                    });


            ViewData["ListofProfiles"] = new SelectList(ListofProfiles, "Value", "Text");

            return View(ddl);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid the `ViewData` approach.Switch to Strongly typed way of doing this. Add another property to your View Model to carry one more dropdown items

```
public class User
{
  public int SelectedCountry { set;get;}
  public int SelectedProfile { set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Countries  {set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Profiles {set;get;}

  public User()
  {
     Countries =new List<SelectListItem>(); 
     Profiles =new List<SelectListItem>(); 
  }
}
```

Now set the collection in your `GET` action

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new User();
  vm.Countries=GetCountryItems();
  vm.Profiles=GetProfileItems();  
  return View(vm);
}
```

Where `GetCountryItems` and `GetProfileItems` are 2 methods which returns a list of SelectListItem objects for countries and Profiles from db.

***Do not make your controllers FAT. Just keep it simple and clean. Move away your code which fetch data from repository to a different layer. Easy to read and maintain :)***

And in your strongly typed view,

```
@mode User
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry,
                     new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProfile,
                     new SelectList(Model.Profiles, "Value", "Text"), "Select")
 <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Hello again Shyju. Glad know you got my back on starting up on this.

Comment: I checked out your website. I look forward to seeing your CRM solution.